# discard nearly identical rowset

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm executing a query and I'm getting a result set where I have 2 nearly identical rows, where only one column value is different - 'EXPLICIT_PERM'.

The query itself is quite long and I can't post it here, but I can say that the value of 'EXPLICIT_PERM' is determined within the query as result of another column's value, its structure is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ((QUERY1)UNION ALL (QUERY2) UNION ALL (QUERY3));
```

The query returns many results, but on rare occasions this duplicate scenario can occur.

[image: QUERY RESULTS]

Is there a way I can check if I get two identical SERVER_IDs and discard the result the contains '0' as EXPLICIT_PERM?

Comment: How about simply using where in the outer side, I mean out of the union all's bracket?

Comment: I need to discard the row where EXPLICIT_PERM=0, only in case a server ID appears twice, how can I detect that?

Comment: Why do you want to solve this with PL/SQL (a programming language) and not with SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, this may be a way.
Assuming you already have you r query giving a result, you can wrap it this way:

```
with yourResult(server_id, server_name, explicit_perm, rank, total) as (
    select 93, 'AVIZNER', 1, 1, 10 from dual union all
    select 93, 'AVIZNER', 0, 6, 10 from dual union all
    select 11, 'XXXXXXX', 1, 1, 10 from dual union all
    select 22, 'YYYYYYY', 0, 1, 10 from dual union all
    select 11, 'ZZZZZZZ', 1, 1, 11 from dual union all
    select 11, 'ZZZZZZZ', 1, 2, 22 from dual union all
    select 11, 'ZZZZZZZ', 0, 1, 10 from dual
)
select server_id, server_name, explicit_perm, rank, total
from (
        select server_id, server_name, explicit_perm, rank, total,
               count ( case when explicit_perm = 1 then 1 end) over ( partition by server_id) as count_perm_1
        from yourResult
     )
where not ( explicit_perm = 0 and count_perm_1 > 0)
```

This counts the number of rows with `explicit_perm = 1` for every `server_id` and then excludes the rows for which `explicit_perm = 0` and at least one row with `explicit_perm = 1` exists for the same `server_id`.

The result with my sample data:

```
 SERVER_ID SERVER_ EXPLICIT_PERM       RANK      TOTAL
---------- ------- ------------- ---------- ----------
        11 ZZZZZZZ             1          2         22
        11 ZZZZZZZ             1          1         11
        11 XXXXXXX             1          1         10
        22 YYYYYYY             0          1         10
        93 AVIZNER             1          1         10
```

Comment: I just noticed that after adding this to my query, the ORDER BY I perform got messed up. I do not order by the 'server_id' column, but when I remove this part from the query, the order is restored back to normal. Any idea why?

Comment: You can not rely on an ordering without an ORDER BY in the external query. If you need to order for some criteria, the only safe way is by adding an ORDER BY clause to the query tht wraps you initial query.

Comment: I added an ORDER BY in the external query as well, that resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach is to rank your result rows (in your case per `SERVER_ID`) and only keep the best-ranked. You do this with `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    row_number() over (partition by server_id order by explicit_term desc) as rn,
    q.*
  from (<your query>) q
)
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to all the other interesting solutions. we may also try group by clause

```
SELECT service_id, 
       server_nam, 
       max(explicit_perm) explicit_perm, 
       rank, 
       total
 FROM ((QUERY1)UNION ALL (QUERY2) UNION ALL (QUERY3))
 group by service_id, server_nam, rank, total;
```